# How do I compare a date field with the current time in a twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, datetime

I have a date field on a node – set to a custom date format (*c* which is ISO) in the Manage Display.
I have a twig template checking to see if that date field comes before today, in which is should output *Past*.
Outputting the fields/comparison values gets me the properly formatted dates I want to compare.

```
{{ content.field_closing_date.0 }}
{{ 'now'|date('c') }}
```

which outputs

```
2021-05-05T16:30:00-07:00
2021-05-14T12:01:53-07:00
```

My comparison is

```
{% if 'now'|date('c') > content.field_closing_date.0 %}
Past
{% endif %}
```

But it's not outputting *Past*. What gives?
You can see that the todays date *does* come after the date field.

Comment: Do this in a preprocess function or service and be sure to account for server or user timezone, whichever is applicable. The logic will be cleaner and saner, if it's a service it can be tested too.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like a preprocess function is overload and if you can afford to ignore timezones, try converting both date values to **U**nix timestamps to make them properly comparable. And prefer raw node values over formatted content values:

```
{% if ('now'|date('U') > node.field_closing_date.0.value|date('U')) %}
  Past
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code in the node template, you can compare the closing date value with the current date and print whatever you want based on that.

```
{% set current_date = "now"|date("Y-m-d") %}
{% set closing_date = node.field_closing_date.value|date("Y-m-d") %}

{% if closing_date < current_date %}
  Past
{% elseif closing_date > current_date %}
  Future
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my code to compare the current time with a date field for views twig tempplate

```
{% if content.field_expired_date.0['#markup']|date('U') >= "now"|date('U') %}
    Hello Future 
{% endif %}
```